Read-only mode issue?
Whenever I access the site normally, the banner says Worldbuilding.SE is in read-only mode so I can't log in. Refreshing doesn't work. However, this problem disappears if I go on other stacks or if I access W.SE on incognito mode or another device. This is a very recent development, just several minutes ago when I first posted this. From what I can tell, this is a problem specific to me.
I'm posting this question on incognito if it matters. What issue am I experiencing?

This is a recent-ish issue (maybe couple of months old) that seems to affect users randomly. It is somewhat rare but with enough users somebody eventually gets affected.
It is also localised per site and machine - a user might see site A as read only but not site B. But on another machine they might be able to interact with site A.
The current workaround is to to clear your cache and cookies to get rid of it.
Here are reports on Meta Stack Exchange for tracking purposes:

SO in read-only mode, status not updated
Read-only mode - misleading?
Stack Overflow appears in "read-only mode", but only on a specific machine in specific browser
Stack Overflow in read-only mode for past 2 days

